# Importing nodes directly into database

Tags: 7, importing-exporting

I have created a custom content type and fields.

i want to import data into content type.

best solution for import data ?

i can export of database for example .CSV .XML

i don't know best solution for import data into drupal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [Node Export](http://drupal.org/project/node_export).

1. Create one example node from your content-type
2. Export it to e.g. CSV
3. add your other nodes
4. re-import CSV

Answer (score 1):

Use the [feeds](http://drupal.org/project/feeds) module it has CSV importer which works well. If you need to transform the data consider using the [migrate](http://drupal.org/project/migrate) module which is more time consuming but gives more flexibility